# Nginx reverse proxy trailing slash

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite, node.js, rules

This question is already answered multiple times but in my case there is a twist.

I am having a node app which is running on port 3000. I am using nginx to reverse proxy. Now the application only works if there is a slash in the end.

So this works: `https://example.com/main/site/react/`

This does not: `https://example.com/main/site/react`

Here is the configuration which I am using:

```
location /main/site/react {
    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;
    rewrite ^/main/site/react/(?:|[\w\/]+)(\/static.*)$ $1 break;
    rewrite ^/main/site/react/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
}
```

After checking other related questions, adding following rewrite rule(after `error_log`) worked for me:

```
rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

Above rule rendered my node application, but it failed with my static resources. I have some static resources rewrites which are not working.

So this URL is not working: `https://example.com/main/site/react/static/js/bundle.js`. It always renders index HTML page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config looks good. Just add the rewrite at the end:

```
location /main/site/react {
    rewrite ^/main/site/react$ https://$host/main/site/react/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/main/site/react/(?:|[\w\/]+)(\/static.*)$ $1 break;
    rewrite ^/main/site/react/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

Also have modified regex which will handle slash before query params.